# How to increase access token expiry time using fb_exchange_token with OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-access-token

I am using FB.login to login to Facebook on my web site and it works.

I can get the accessToken with response.AuthResponse.accessToken easily.

The session is valid for 2 hours. I understand from what I read that with fb_exchange_token you can extend it to 30 days or 60 days (I am not sure which, I saw both numbers).

**Question 1:** Is this doable in Javascript? Do I need to provide the app secret (which I don't want to do in Javascript because everyone would have access to it)? Could someone kindly provide a code snippet to do that?

My plan is to send the newly acquired extended token to PHP using ajax and then use it for the PHP FQL calls I am doing. Currently I am doing:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $app_id,'secret' => $app_secret));

$fql = 'SELECT first_name, last_name, movies, tv, FROM user WHERE uid =' . $uid;

$param = array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $fql,'callback' => '');

$fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);
```

**Question 2:** This is probably a newbie question, but how do I use the new access token sent by ajax in the PHP code above? Currently, I am not explicitly using an access token and everything works (up until the 2 hours expires).

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regis

Answer (score 1):

When you get you access token back from Facebook you should send it back to the server, you can then extend it there without worrying about exposing your app key and secret.

Once you have the access token on the server you can add it to the Facebook library using the following method.

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token)
```

Any api calls you make will then be performed as the logged in user.